# How to play DVD with Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: vlc, dvd

I have an external USB DVD drive which works fine with my Win7 laptop; however, when I connect it to my netbook (Ubuntu 14.04), it will not play commercial (encrypted) DVDs.

I have installed the VLC player, libdvdcss2, libdvdread4, libdvdnav4. If I select the no menu option in VLC, I get the message "Playback failure: DVDRead could not read - 1/4 blocks at 0x22a7." VLC does, however, display the name and length of the movie.

This is apparently a software issue since the DVD drive and DVD work fine with WIn7.

Comment: Try run `sudo ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/dvd`

Comment: try smplayer,  it may work for you, to download it. go to a terminal and write: sudo apt-get install smplayer. you may also need to download Ubuntu extras from Ubuntu software center. JMO

Comment: Liso and Ronnie - Thanks for the suggestions, but still does not work.

Comment: Will it play unprotected DVDs?

Comment: Not sure - all the DVDs I have are commercial, store-bought  movies.

Answer (score 3):

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run following command to install require dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder libdvdread4 totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame nautilus-script-audio-convert libmad0 mpg321 && sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Restart may necessary.

WARNING: Run encrypted video on Linux is illegal, so make sure its legal on your area.

See also:

- [Why it is legal to play encrypted video on Linux ?](http://www.itworld.com/article/2756942/open-source-tools/legalizing-linux-dvd-playback--why-bother-.html)
- [Watching DVDs legal on USA](http://www.howtogeek.com/138969/why-watching-dvds-on-linux-is-illegal-in-the-usa/)

  **UPDATE**

Since medibuntu is no longer available, you have to install `libdvdcss2` manually :

```
wget http://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable/libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.13-0_i386.deb
```

Now encrypted dvd should run perfectly fine

Comment: This saved my life when i promised my daughter watching Frozen from DVD :-)

Comment: Since I have already installed, uninstalled, reinstalled VLC, libdvdread4, etc., would it help to do it again? Would sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh install something different than what is already there?

Comment: Yes! Without this, nothing will work.

Comment: I guess I spoke too soon, Liso and iacobus. The DVD played for about 15 minutes and then went back to the VLC menu. Also, while I am able to select a submenu from the main menu, anything I select on any submenu causes the DVD to quit and puts me back at the VLC menu.

Comment: @RetiredGuy that is due to encryption; not all encryption methods have been deciphered so it is a bit of hit and miss watching dvds. You are better off downloading the content of the DVD (and yes I know ...).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `libdvdcss2` from [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/ubuntu/trusty/)
and then try VLC again.

`libdvdcss` is a simple library designed for accessing DVDs like a block device without having to bother about the decryption.

Comment: libdvdcss is already installed. Does the link point to a different version?

Comment: I don't know which version you have. You can determine it using 'aptitude show libdvdcss2' command. Also please read about region codes here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs .